# Don't Understand Apple's takeFloatValueFrom: Example

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm no iOS guru but I know enough to build apps. I know and understand the patterns, UIKit, and Objective-C. I'm now learning Mac Development and this little bit of ["Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/WhatAreBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002372-CJBEJBHH) has me stumped:

> Take as an example a very simple application in which the values in a text field and a slider are kept synchronized. Consider first an implementation that does not use bindings. **The text field and slider are connected directly to each other using target-action, where each is the other’s target and the action is `takeFloatValueFrom:`** as shown in Figure 2. (If you do not understand this, you should read *Getting Started With Cocoa*.)
>
> [image]
>
> This example illustrates the dynamism of the Cocoa environment—**the values of two user interface objects are kept synchronized without writing any code, even without compiling**.

*(Emphasis mine)*

Huh? Wouldn't you need to create outlets? And an IBAction that goes something like

```
- (IBAction)takeFloatValueFrom:(id)sender {
    self.slider.floatValue = [sender floatValue];
    self.textField.floatValue = [sender floatValue];
}
```

Is this something Mac-specific? How do you actually hook up two controls with target-action in a XIB without writing any code and have their values locked?

Comment: and where does one find "Getting Started With Cocoa"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're setting up an interface in Interface Builder, you can specify that it sends a message to another object whenever it changes in some way. What this example is showing is that you can hook these two objects up such that whenever the slider changes, it sends the message `takeFloatValueFrom:` to the text field, and vice-versa.

[`takeFloatValueFrom:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/takeFloatValueFrom:) is a method defined on `NSControl`, and both a text field and a slider are subclasses of `NSControl`.

Comment: Is this macOS specific?